# GitHub shows incorrect commit dates with force push after git rebase

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-rebase

On a new branch, I amended an older commit message by using the `reword` option in a `git rebase`. But, after doing a force push with `git push -f`, GitHub shows different commit history dates with all the newer commits, including the amended commit, under the current date. But, doing `git log` on the local branch shows the correct commit dates. How can I force push the branch so that GitHub shows the correct commit dates?

Comment: Try `git log --format=fuller`